# Powershell allow user to offline cluster resource based on list

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a powershell script to extract a number of generic clustered services which are running. I want the user to be able to select which resource they want to offline based on a number choice. So for example

```
$DisplayServices = Get-ClusterResource | Select-Object -Property Name | Format-Table
```

This displays the list like this

```
ClusterService.clearingA.Processor                                                                                 
ClusterService.clearingB.Processor                                                                                  
ClusterService.clearingH.Processor
ClusterService.clearingS.Processor
ClusterService.clearinS.Processor
ClusterService.clearingSSProcessor
ClusterService.clearingZZ.Processor
```

I want to allow the user to have a option say 1-10 of which service they want to offline. So based on the readhost response it then does below

```
Get-ClusterResource | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*SpecificName*'} | stop-ClusterResource
```

So, rather then type the full name i want to have a display which shows

```
1 ClusterService.clearingA.Processor                                                                                 
2 ClusterService.clearingB.Processor                                                                                  
3 ClusterService.clearingH.Processor
4 ClusterService.clearingS.Processor
5 ClusterService.clearinS.Processor
6 ClusterService.clearingSSProcessor
7 ClusterService.clearingZZ.Processor
```

Then if they type 2 the script goes and does this

```
Get-ClusterResource | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*ClusterService.clearingB.Processor*'} | stop-ClusterResource
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  What is your question here?  It looks like you have all of the pieces you need, and just need to assemble them into a script.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the `-Passthru` parameter to `Out-Gridview`.  It displays a list of items as a UI and allows the user to choose one, which is then passed on to the pipeline.  This seems to be exactly what you're trying to do here.

```
Get-ClusterResource | Out-Gridview -Passthru | stop-ClusterResource
```

`Out-Gridview -Passthru` behaves like an interactive `Where-Object` clause.  When the window comes up, the user can select one of the items (or multiselect using Ctrl or Shift) and those items will be passed via the pipeline to the next command.

Comment: That works. Thank you. I guess there is no way via the console to do this?

Comment: @ADTJOB You mean put the list in the console and have the user input a number there?  Sure.  You were on the right track.  Display the list to console, then call `Read-Host` to get the user input, then act on it.  There's no built-in cmdlet as simple as `Out-Gridview` for it though.

Comment: Thanks. But how do i stop a resource based on number selected. For example would it be an if statement. This could get very long so i was hoping to dynamically display number and resource name. Then pass number back and stop or start service based on what number corresponded with resource. Hope that makes sense